# Polarization modulation

Tags: visible-light, polarization

To increase bandwidth, for EM free space communication, could you modulate the polarization, so that, e.g., for  a one-meter wavelength radio wave, the polarization could be modulated between vertical and horizontal one million times, which would mean a (possibly) different polarization each micrometer in a one meter wave?

I assume this is not possible, but wonder why.

Comment: can be done but is inefficient because you might as well use both polarizations modulated. If you modulate faster than the carrier then the bandwidth expands so that you are in the so-called ultra-wideband regime where it is very difficult to have the antenna keep the polarizations orthogonal.

Comment: If this polarization modulation was used just in near field, would it have same inefficiency?